# Protecting against overflow in a delay function

Tags: c, integer-overflow, mcu

I have in a project of mine a small delay function that I have written myself by making use of a timer peripheral of my MCU:

static void delay100Us(void)

```
{
  uint_64 ctr = TIMER_read(0); //10ns resolution
  uint_64 ctr2 = ctr + 10000;
  while(ctr <= ctr2) //wait 100 microseconds(10000)
  {
      ctr = TIMER_read(0);
  }
}
```

The counter is a freerunning hw counter with 10ns resolution so I wrote that function as to give approximately 100us delay.
I think this should work in principle however there could be the situation where the timer is less than 10000 from overflowing and so ctr2 will get assigned a value which is more than ctr can actually reach and therefore I would end up getting stuck into an infinite loop.

I need to generate a delay using this timer in my project so I need to somehow make sure that I always get the same delay(100us) while at the same time protect myself from getting stuck there.

Is there any way I can do this or is this just a limitation that I can't get passed?

Thank you!

Edit:

```
ctr_start = TimerRead(); //get initial value for the counter
interval = TimerRead() - ctr_start;
while(interval <= 10000)
{
  interval = ( TimerRead() - ctr_start  + countersize ) % countersize;
}

Where countersize = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: If the counter is unsigned then it should wrap. Look at the elapsed *interval* mod the max counter value. Time is up when the interval is (here) > 10000. `interval = (timer - ctr + countersize) % countersize` If it's a 64-bit counter then `interval = timer - ctr`. Do the arithmetic before checking the interval (to allow the arithmetic to wrap).

Comment: The maximum value of 64 bits is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. IMO it's best to use a free-run counter with a total period in excess of the max you'll ever need. If the counter is 64-bit it is simple. Mark the start value, then compute the elapsed *interval* and compare it. Use `>=` so you don't need to catch an exact value. If it is a 32-bit counter then use `uint32_t` types, etc.

Comment: ...so don't compute a target as you have done, work with the elapsed interval.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have modified it like this: see original post edit.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think I understood your solution if it's correct what I edited in the main post can you make a reply so I can accept it as answer?

Comment: Perhaps you could clear the timer and then do the software wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be dangerous to wait for a specific timer value in case an interrupt happens at just that moment and you miss the required count. So it is better to wait until the counter has reached *at least* the target value. But as noticed, comparing the timer with a target value creates a problem when the target is lower than the initial value.

One way to avoid this problem is to consider the **interval** that has elapsed with `unsigned` variables and arithmetic. Their behaviour is well defined when values wrap.

A hardware counter is almost invariably of size 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits, so choose a variable type to suit. Suppose the counter is 32-bit:

```
void delay(uint32_t period)
{
    uint32_t mark = TIMER_read(0);
    uint32_t interval;
    do {
        interval = TIMER_read(0) - mark;    // underflow is well defined
    } while(interval < period);
}
```

Obviously, the required period must be less than the counter's period. If not, either scale the timer's clock, or use another method (such as a counter maintained by interrupt).

Sometimes a one-shot timer is used to count down the required period, but using a free-run counter is easy, and using a one-shot timer means it can't be used by another process at the same time.